# Integer to String: Without using stoi library

Tags: c++

I found this question in the book where it asks us to transfer an Int to a string. Without using stoi library
so for example if x = 10, s="10"
the code should handle negative numbers.

I found this solution in the book. I typed it in my compiler however it is giving the string of the first number only

so if x= 45, it is giving "4"

I do not understand this line `s = '0' + x%10;` to be able to fix the code.
why is he adding '0' to the string. What is the best solution.

here is the code: I added comments to the parts I understand

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


void IntToString(int x);
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> num;

    IntToString(num);
}

void IntToString(int x)
{
    bool isNegative = false;
    if(x < 0)         //if its negative make boolean true 
    {
        x = -x;
        isNegative = true;
    }
    string s;
    do
    {
        s = '0' + x%10;    //modulus for getting the last number
        x = x/10;   //shorten the number
    }while(x); 
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end()); //reverse the string since it starts from end

    if(isNegative)
        s = '-' + s;
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: Adding a value from 0-9 to '0' gives you the ASCII characters for '0' - '9'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `do ... while` loop is that you just extract the last digit of the changed `x` only to replace it with the second last digit and so on, until you get the first digit of `x` stored in `s`.

There is no effect of `reverse(s.begin(), s.end())` since `s` practically holds only one character.

Also, we add `'0'` to `s` because `s` initially stores the integer value of the number, and adding `'0'` converts it into its ASCII form.

Example:

```
void IntToString(int x)
{
    bool isNegative = false;
    if(x < 0)
    {
        x = -x;
        isNegative = true;
    }
    string s;
    do
    {
        //The below code appends the new number at the beginning of s.
        s = ('0' + x%10) + s;    //modulus for getting the last number
        x = x/10;   //shorten the number
    }while(x); 
    if(isNegative)
        main_string = '-' + main_string;
    cout << main_string << endl;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `main_string = s + main_string;` simply `s += '0' + x%10;` would do

Answer (score 3):

```
s = '0' + x%10;
```

will grabs the last digit from `x%10` and add ASCII of `0` i.e. 48, giving the ASCII of desired last digit, which get copy assigned to string `s` using its assignment operator.

And btw, you need :

```
s += '0' + x%10;
  ~~ // += operator
```

Comment: intresting. I thought static_cast does that